# Como puedo renderizar un componente desde otro con react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Estoy construyendo una app que trabaja con react-navigation y personalice los botones del drawer y entre estos hay un componente en el drawer que dibuja la foto y nombre del usuario que se obtienen mediante una petición asincronica hecha desde el mismo lugar donde se define el drawer de la siguiente manera:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"; 
import {createDrawerNavigator} from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { MainStackNavigator, HomeStackNavigator } from "./StackNavigator";
import ButtonsDrawer from "../components/Navigation/ButtonsDrawer";
import HostBackend from "../resources/Utils/hostBackend";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    const [id,setId] = useState(null);
    const [img,setImg] = useState(null);
    const [name,setName] = useState(null);
    const [tag,setTag] = useState(null);

    (
        async () => {
            const response = await fetch(HostBackend.root + '/api/user',{
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                credentials: 'include',
            });

            const content = await response.json();

            if(content.id != undefined){
                setId(content.id.toString());
                setName(content.name);
            }

            const responseTwo = await fetch(HostBackend.root + '/api/profile',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                credentials: 'include',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'id' : id
                })
            });

            const contentTwo = await responseTwo.json();

            if(contentTwo.user != undefined){
                setImg(contentTwo.photo);
                setTag(contentTwo.tag);
            }
        }
    )();

    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
            }}

            drawerContent={({navigation}) => {
                if(id != null){
                    return (
                        <ButtonsDrawer 
                        img={img}
                        name={name}
                        tag={tag}
                        home={() => navigation.navigate('HomeStack')}
                        config={() => navigation.navigate('Config')}
                        profile={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
                        saves={() => navigation.navigate('Saves')}
                        contribute={() => navigation.navigate('Contributes')}
                        thread={() => navigation.navigate('Threads')}
                        />
                    )
                }
            }}
        >
            <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={MainStackNavigator}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={HomeStackNavigator}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

Como se logra ver hago una petición asincronica con la que obtengo los datos del usuario y la paso como variables al componente ButtonsDrawer pero para poder obtener estos datos depende de estar logueado, entonces si la app inicia y no esta logueado asi se loguee esos elementos no se cargan el drawer, si reinicio la app ya con el token de login si los carga pero necesito poder hacer que este componente se renderice nuevamente al llegar al home o si existe otra manera estaria muy agradecido de saberla.